# Does my light switch have a ground?

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, smart-switch

I just bought my first house and I want to replace this switch with

[This smart switch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01EZV35QU).

The smart switch says it needs a ground wire, but when I opened the box up, it looks like there are only two wires here.

Is this box grounded? Would I need the ground wire?

See below for pictures:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think you, or the instructions, are confusing the ground and the neutral, smart switches need a  neutral. There does appears to be neutrals in the box, they are White, underneath that  paint. You do also need a ground which is bare wire and  in the box also. It should be attached to the green screw on the switch.

Comment: @AlaskaMan, this is the switch I had in mind: https://www.amazon.com/Kasa-Smart-Light-Switch-TP-Link/dp/B01EZV35QU/ref=sr_1_5?dchild=1&keywords=smart+switch&qid=1609196417&sr=8-5

So that bundle on the left is neutral, and the bare copper on the right is ground?

Comment: Yes i can see the grounds in a wire nut. The other wire nut may be neutrals but  i can not tell from here. Jack has it right.

Comment: @alaskaman there are some smart switches that require a grounding conductor. These are designed for systems with no neutral.  I saw a top 10 web site no neutral but did not look to see if they were UL listed. GE was one of the mfg’s and I believe lutron also makes one

Comment: @AlaskaMan Yeah, what Ed Beal says.  UL gives a waiver for this: the products are designed so there is no failure mode that would ever leak more than a few milliamps of current onto the ground.  Normally they leak <0.5ma to ground so several won't trip a GFCI.   I thought I saw where NEC limits any given circuit to 8 smart switches, that would explain why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your light switch is not grounded and neither is the plastic box. You do have a ground wire in the box. It's the bare copper wires wire nutted together. To ground a switch, you'd need to get a piece of 14 AWG wire and connect it to the group of bare copper wires and then to the switch.
Most smart switches need a neutral, which isn't the same as a ground. The neutrals would be a group of white wires connected by a wire nut. Scrape some of the paint off the wires to make sure of the colors. Make sure the power's off before doing any work.

Comment: Correct, if the neutrals are present then you can pigtail to the switch just like the ground. Pigtail means adding a short piece of wire to the wire nut group and then that to the switch.

Comment: Looking at the switch you linked to i see it has wires instead of terminal screws, so no pigtails are needed, just add the wires from the switch to the existing wire nuts.

Comment: @AlaskaMan  Thank you for that  in depth definition of "pigtail".  :-)

Comment: Thanks to you both! Good to know I can use the wires in the switch without getting additional wire for a pigtail!